# Is it necessary to check if element has attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using data attributes in HTML elements

Example:

```
<div class="fruit" data-color="red">...</div>
```

In jQuery I'm getting the data attribute using `$(this).data("color")` and adding it has a class name to the element.

Is it necessary to validate first if a data attribute exists before adding it as a class? Example:

```
// $(this) is .fruit div
if ( $(this).data("color") ) {
   $(this).addClass($(this).data("color")); //adds data value as class to element
}
```

or does jQuery handle that? I tried running the code without the if statement and I don't get any errors if the element has no "color" data attribute. I'm guessing that jQuery just ignores it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery handles that for you - in fact it's very robust in what it will accept for most method parameters without throwing any errors.

In this case if the `data` attribute is not found (or has no value) it will return `undefined`. If you then `addClass(undefined)` jQuery will perform no action on the selected elements.